# How to combine two Shopify sections in a tab inside a .json template

Tags: javascript, html, json, shopify, liquid

How to add 2 Shopify sections in a tab inside a .json template

I am using the Shopify Gecko theme by The4.
They have 2 available sections for recommending products in Shopify. These are the "recently-viewed" section and the "product-recommendations" section.

I am trying to add these 2 sections in a tab using nested sections and liquid but haven't succeeded.
I need help on how to do this.

The previous Gecko theme wasn't Shopify 2.0 ready, so these sections were rendered as snippets using liquid coding. But the new Gecko theme has updated to Shopify 2.0 and the old snippets are now rendered as sections.

The old collection.liquid template is also now a .json template called liquid.json and I don't know how to add combine these 2 sections into a tab.

Is it possible to add HTML code into .json?

This is the previous code I used to combine the snippets into a tab.

```
  <!-- Collection Tab Slider -->
  <div class="collection-tab-slider">
    <div class="tab collection-tab-header">
      <div class="button tablinks tab-title" onclick="openTabs(event, 'tab1')" id="defaultOpen">You might also like</div>
      <div class="button tablinks tab-title" onclick="openTabs(event, 'tab2')">Recently viewed</div>
    </div>
  <!-- Tab content -->
    <div id="tab1" class="tabcontent">
      {%- section 'featured_collection_owl' -%}
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tabcontent">
      {%- section 'recently_viewed' -%}
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
  function openTabs(evt, TabName) {
  // Declare all variables
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

  // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
  document.getElementById(TabName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";  
  }
  
  // Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
  document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();  
  </script>
```